# Definition of "identical in distribution"

Tags: probability-theory, definition

While one can find various online references (and in books) for the definition of "convergence in distribution", I have several times today been stumped (as a non-probabilist) by the notion of "identical/equal in distribution" or "identity/equality in distribution".   This seems to be notated with $\stackrel{d}{=}$.  Does it mean something like equal almost everywhere in analysis?  Are there any easy/obvious examples someone with only a first course in probability could understand?

---

I could not find a reference in the books in front of me (unfortunately I didn't have Feller handy) nor on the internet, including this site - the latter of which I found pretty surprising.  But I'll be happy to close this if it's a dup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how much you know about probability theory this might be of help.

A random variable $X$ has a probability distribution function ("cumulative distribution function" or CDF), denoted $F_X$, for which $P(X\le t) = F_X(t)$.  Two different random variables $X$ and $Y$ can have the same probability  distribution functions, in which case we say they are "equal in distribution", written $X\stackrel{d}{=}Y$, or $F_X=F_Y$.

What is a random variable?  A measurable function on a probability measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$.  The distribution function of the random variable $X$ is then $F_X(t)=P(\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)\le t\})$.  The strange thing about equality in distribution is that $X$ and $Y$ might be functions on completely different probability spaces and yet be equal in distribution.

For example, suppose you and I each have a fair coin. You flip yours, and report the result $X$ as a $0$ or $1$; I flip mine similarly to get $Y$. Our two results are equal in distribution, even though there is no claim that $X=Y$.

Comment: Wow.  That is a LOT simpler than I was anticipating.  So basically equal in distribution means the pdf/cdf is the same, even though the respective event spaces of course might not be.  Thanks.

Comment: Now the next question is why is this definition not in any of the several texts I consulted?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You've got it.  As to your second comment: good question.  Maybe it's in one or 2 of them tucked away where you didn't notice. One does see the equivalent term "identically distributed", though.

Comment: I'll check Feller at work tomorrow.  Maybe most undergrad texts don't use this terminology, even though obviously it is necessary for even the most simple examples like yours.  Thanks again!